# How to view Elastic Search configuration settings from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to list the current config settings of the Elastic Search instance with Kibana?
I don't have easy access to the installation file system (hence its configuration myl file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there isn't a way to see *all* of the settings via the API

there is the [`_nodes` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/cluster-nodes-info.html) that contains some of it, but it doesn't pull in everything